# Is it possible to calculate the total amount of data that were transfer through web sockets using chrome?

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

We have a requirement to find the total amount of data transfer in our javascript application.
We are using both http and web-sockets for transferring data. Is it possible to calculate the amount of data that were transfer through each web-socket messages. We are using socket.io library for implementing web-socket connection.

Comment: On what level do you wish to see the data? On application level or on TCP/IP level. The size of data you put into a stream or the total size of TCP packets being sent/received?

Comment: We need to save total size of data in application level.